# Is the definite article in Hebrew used to convert an adjective or adverb into a noun, or used without a noun?

Tags: hebrew, grammar

This question requires a degree of Hebrew scholarship, although if someone has the means (software) to compile a list of Old Testament examples where articles precede adjectives or adverbs *without a noun,* I would be happy for this as well.

Essentially, the question seeks to know whether, on occasion, a Hebrew word that is not otherwise a noun can be made one by prefixing the definite article to it.

English examples where this seems true might be something like:

"The more, the merrier."

"The less you say, the better."

"The more you study, the more you learn."

Apparently these English constructions are called "comparative correlatives." But I am not interested in the English--I would like to know if any similar rule exists for Hebrew grammar.

A corollary question would be: *Does Hebrew use articles without a noun?*

Here is a Hebrew example of which I am aware in which no noun exists following an article:

> וְעַ֥ד שַֽׂר־הַצָּבָ֖א הִגְדִּ֑יל וּמִמֶּ֨נּוּ֙ הרים הַתָּמִ֔יד
> וְהֻשְׁלַ֖ךְ מְכֹ֥ון מִקְדָּשֹֽׁו׃  (Daniel 8:11, MT / TR)

The word "הַתָּמִ֔יד" has the article prefix followed by an adverb (meaning daily, routinely, or continually).  Most English translations have added a noun afterward, perhaps expecting the article to require one.  This same pattern is seen in the next two verses, and in Daniel 11:31 and 12:11.

Are there more such examples, and/or a grammatical expectation to apply to situations like this, without necessitating the addition of a gloss?

Comment: התמיד in hebrew actually is a noun in that context. It refers to the daily sacrifice of the temple (two sheeps, one in the morning one in the evening)

Comment: @Kapandaria The word "sacrifice" is not there.  It was added by people who _theorize_ that it belongs based on what they have observed in other places.  But Daniel was no ordinary linguist, and this is presumptive on the part of translators.

Comment: Indeed the word sacrifice is not there, but I am jewish learner, and I know hebrew, and in this specific context, that word is a noun.

Comment: The article is not necessarily.  Look a participles and infinitives.  However, in Hebrew the participle is also used to express a present tense meaning.

Comment: @Kapandaria Are you saying that the word translated as "daily" was a noun because of the article before it?  If so, please submit this, with support for it, as an answer.

Comment: @PerryWebb  But aren't participles and infinitives verb forms?  If I'm not mistaken, this "daily" is an adverb here, and neither a participle nor an infinitive.  Please feel free to clarify, ...or submit an answer!

Comment: Look at the word רֹעֶה. It is a participle of רָעָה, but is also a noun meaning shepherd.

Comment: The noun אֹ֫כֶל is essentially a particle, so that "he eats food" is הוא אוכל אוכל.

Comment: התמיד is a nickname for the daily sacrifice. It's also called תמידין in plural, because they are two. But I think you can find other examples

Comment: An article explaining definiteness  in Hebrew can be found here. 

  [1]: https://uhg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/definiteness.html